# What is the chance a survivor will get better?

Tags: state-of-decay

When a survivor falls ill or is seriously injured, there is a chance that they may become infected and may not heal from that injection. This will result in the survivor turning into a zombie, who will then attack other members of your party at your base.

An ill survivor may be highlighted with the mission "Mercy Killing", which will give you three options;

- Kill the survivor
- Evict the survivor from your base
- Defer the decision until later

[image]

If you defer the decision, what are the chances of the survivor becoming infected and turning into a zombie? Is this related to the amount of medicine you have on base or any other factors? Is it worth always killing off a survivor in case they turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, all you can do to treat a survivor is to have a medical area and medicine. The medical area, from my experience will treat a survivor better if it is upgraded to either the infirmary or medical lab. Having a surplus of medicine will also help quite a bit to heal and treat people.