# If a survivor gets a “Sick: Gravely Ill” status, is there a chance that they will still get better?

Tags: state-of-decay

If a survivor gets a “Sick: Gravely Ill – Could go at any time” status, like shown in the screenshot below, is there a chance that they will still get better, or is all hope lost? If they can get better, how do I increase their chances?

[image: screenshot (description is in text above)]

Comment: I know there's a related question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/144266/4797) which some may see that this question is a duplicate of. That question talks about survivors that give the 'Mercy Killing' quest, while in this question I'm talking about survivors that just got the ‘Sick: Gravely Ill’ status, not necessarily giving the 'Mercy Killing' quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Medical Area](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Medical_Area) upgraded to Infirmary and someone with [Medicine](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Medicine) skill can increase sickness/wound recovery chance to 50% per in-game day. You can see the wikia link for more details.

Comment: Can you confirm that this can increase the recovery chance of someone whose status is 'Sick: Gravely Ill'?

Comment: Yes. With that setup, you achieve maximum recovery chance of 50/50 for ALL types of injury or sickness. Someone has also mentioned the method of deliberately wounding the character so that the injury would "override" the sickness status, but I can't confirm that.

Comment: +1, I can confirm that this works. You have to have medicine resources available. It can take awhile, as in real-life days.